# beforeSend does not add authorization header to my jquery ajax call (basic authorization)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, basic-authentication

I have been trying to make an $ajax() call to a rest service. I need to use basic authentication to make this call, so i added the beforeSend handler to my ajax call. When I trace this in Fiddler, I dont see it attaching the authorization header to my request.

```
<body>
<div id="Button1" style="border: 2px solid blue; font-family: Cambria;">
    Get CMS Content
</div>
<br />
<div id="error" style="color: Red; font-family: Cambria; font-size: large; display: none;">
</div>
<span style="font-family: Cambria; color: #009933; font-weight: bold">Result:</span>
<div id="result">
</div>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('#error').fadeOut('slow');
            //var requestParams = { 'format': 'json', 'username': 'administrator', 'password': '' };
            var requestParams = { 'format': 'json' };
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjo=");
                },
                url: "http://localhost/KenticoCMS7/rest/cms.country",
                data: requestParams,
                dataType: "text",
                contentType: "application/json;",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#error').fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#result').text(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    $('#error').text(JSON.stringify(xhr));
                    $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Suggestions around this would be of great help. Also, can some one comment on, why fiddler traces this request as a OPTIONS type when it should be of GET type?

Comment: Additionallly, I get a 405 error: 'Method Not Allowed' response on Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **OPTIONS** indicates that this is a CORS request which requires a PREFLIGHT request to determine that the server allows the request method and that credentials are permitted. By returning a HTTP/405, the server indicates that it doesn't support CORS, which causes the subsequent GET request (including its credentials) to never be sent.

Are you sending the request cross-origin?